# Disable pinch zoom in Windows Phone 8 Maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pinchzoom

i need to display some images on maps in WP8, that need to stay at their exact position and cover a specific area (these are pictures of buildings that are displayed on a Road Map)  but
as far as i know there is no way to make that happen when zooming is allowed.

I can get rid of the Double Tap zooming by simply resetting the zoom level, but i have a problem with pinch zooming because this creates a very ugly jumpy effect.

```
private void MapTwo_ZoomLevelChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapZoomLevelChangedEventArgs e)
{
      MyMap.ZoomLevel=16;
}
```

I don't want to disable all user interaction though.

Any advice?

Comment: You've forgotten to show your code...

Comment: I am not sure what code you would like to see